# superclass must be a Class in rspec after ruby upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-2.1

I have a class that looks like this:

```
module API
  module MyNamespace
    class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
  end
end

module API
  module MyNamespace
    class MyClass < Base
    end
  end
end
```

When trying to upgrade from ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.5, I started getting an error when executing the entire spec suite.

`superclass must be a Class (Module given)`

This is strange, because `API::MyNamespace::Base` is a class. Also if I run the tests as part of a smaller run (individual spec, or everything in the API namespace), then everything is fine.

I'm not really sure what to try here.

Comment: I think I hit this once and it's stupid. I think I changed it from actually using the words `module API` etc to just doing `class API::MyNamespace::MyClass` and it was happier with that (even though they're logically equivalent)

Comment: Giving that a go right now, will report back.

Comment: That did it! Odd. Make that an answer and I'll upvote/accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I hit this once and it's stupid. I think I changed it from actually using the words module API etc to just doing

```
class API::MyNamespace::MyClass
```

and it was happier with that (even though they're logically equivalent)